# Kafka Consumer needs a long poll duration

Tags: java, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

Using Kafka/Java with the following configuration:

```
props.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, this.bootstrapServers);
props.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, this.groupId);
props.put(ConsumerConfig.CLIENT_ID_CONFIG, UUID.randomUUID().toString());
props.put(ConsumerConfig.ENABLE_AUTO_COMMIT_CONFIG, false);
props.put(ConsumerConfig.MAX_POLL_RECORDS_CONFIG, this.maxPollRecords);
props.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, keyDeserializerClass.getName());
props.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, valueDeserializerClass.getName());
props.put(ConsumerConfig.ISOLATION_LEVEL_CONFIG, IsolationLevel.READ_COMMITTED.toString().toLowerCase(Locale.ROOT));
```

I have a simple polling loop like:

```
consumer.poll(Duration.ofMillis(200));
```

I noticed some strange behavior. With a 0 duration, it returns no result. Locally with 200 ms duration I get some results, but in another production environment it never returns results, it needs at least 1s.

In my understanding, the poll method will wait until it finds at least a result. With 0 duration, it should at least return the results that are already arrived, it should not always return no result.

What is the explanation?

Answer (score 2):

According to the docs :

```
public ConsumerRecords<K,V> poll​(long timeout)
timeout - The time, in milliseconds, spent waiting in poll if data is not available in the buffer. If 0, returns immediately with any records that are available currently in the buffer, else returns empty. Must not be negative.
```

So, basically as a poll request blocks the thread in which it is being called, poll duration is the maximum time till which it can block the thread. So ,if the timeout is zero or less than the time taken to make a request and get response from consumer, then no records will be returned.

Just for information, if we make this timeout high and set max.poll.records property of consumer to something we want, suppose `max.poll.records : "10"` ,so the poll will itself end after 10 records are fetched (even if timeout is large). So ideally network latency is needed to be know , else the trick I mentioned above works fine.

Answer (score 0):

The main problem is that you might not have stored the output of `poll()`.

`ConsumerRecords records = consumer.poll(10000);`

You need to store the results of `poll` in `ConsumerRecords`. You can find sample code-snippets [here](https://kafka.apache.org/10/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/clients/consumer/KafkaConsumer.html)

Comment: This was just an example. Indeed I store the results in a variable to use them (and it works, with a high-enough poll duration).

Comment: If your Kafka-cluster has been configured with high number of min in-sync replicas and producer is configured with ack=all then data will be available to consumer once all min in-sync replicas get message. This may take some time.

Comment: So tell me about how your cluster has been designed. Kafka recommends to setup a cluster within a data-center. Cluster spanning over different data centers is not recommended. Is your producer and kafka are in the same data center?